# insertion sort logic error in java

Tags: java, exception, insertion-sort

I am trying to implement the insertion sort and I only get the first element correct in the sorted newArray. All others become 0's.

I use the occupancy variable to keep track of the number of elements in the newArray.

```
    package nisarg;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size,i,j,k=0;
        int occupancy = 1;
        System.out.println("How many elements? ");
        size = input.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[size];
        int[] newArray = new int[size];
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter element at " +(i+1) );
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
            //System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        newArray[0] = array[0];
        for(i=1;i<size;i++){
            for(j=0;j<occupancy;j++){
                if(array[i] <= newArray[j]){
                    for(k=occupancy-1;k>j;k--){
                        newArray[k] = newArray[k-1];
                    }
                    newArray[k] = array[i];
                    occupancy++;
                    System.out.println(occupancy +" occupancy");
                    break;
                }
                else if(j==occupancy-1){
                    newArray[occupancy-1] = array[i];
                    occupancy++;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            System.out.println(newArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And which index is out of bounds?

Comment: whatever is the input for the prompt "How many numbers?" or in other words the variable size.

Comment: the occupancy variable is printed out just to help in debugging.

Comment: The problematic statment is `newArray[j]` and this is no surprise. You're increasing the value of `occupancy`, therefore `j` can reach values larger than the size of the array.

Comment: yes i see your point. If I change the inner loop's condition to j < occupancy-1 the exception doesn't arise because at all times j would be less than the size of the newArray

Comment: but there is still a problem with the sorting as I only get the first element correct all others become 0's, which must have something to do with transferring the required variables to the right

Comment: I assume the problem inside of this `if(array[i] <= newArray[j])` block. The first element was overwritten if the second one is smaller (in the original version of your code). For example `3, 1, 2` was sorted to `1, 2, 2`.